# Fetching Text From listed URL using PHP

Tags: php

I have a list of some URL in my Excel sheet like this

http://www.example.com/excel-add-in-google-analytics/?utm_source=ABC&utm_medium=XYZ&utm_content=PQR&utm_campaign=JKL

Now i want to load all this URL one bye in to track and fetch the content and text of it which is place after "?" in new column like this

utm_source ABC
utm_medium XYZ
utm_content PQR 
utm_campaign JKL

using PHP parsing and i don't want to use CURL for this because i already have URL's in my Excelsheet so just want to load it in to PHP script and fetch the text from it..

I doesn't know anything about it so if someone can help me for this and if possible then send me code for it..

Answer (score 0):

```
file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

explode your url to ? and & to get detail of parameter which pass in url

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to read values of url, then:

> **parse_str()** - Parses the string into variables [Read More](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.example.com/excel-add-in-google-analytics/?utm_source=ABC&utm_medium=XYZ&utm_content=PQR&utm_campaign=JKL";
parse_str($url,$values);
print_r($values);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You can use [parse_str](http://www.php.net/parse_str) AND [parse_url](http://www.php.net/parse_url)

```
<?php
$str = "http://www.example.com/excel-add-in-google-analytics/?utm_source=ABC&utm_medium=XYZ&utm_content=PQR&utm_campaign=JKL";

$var = parse_url($str);
parse_str($var['query'], $query);

foreach($query as $key=>$val)
{
    echo $key." ".$val;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PHPExcel library](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to read your excel file and [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) extract the query part of the URL. Let me explain the steps in detail:

First download PHPExcel library from github(in `.zip` format) and extract it to your project directory. Your project directory would look like this:

```
-PHPExcel-1.8 (your extracted library)
   |--Classes
         |--PHPExcel (folder)
         |--PHPExcel.php
   |-- (other things)
-excel.xlsx (your excel sheet)
-index.php (this is where you're going to read and process your excel sheet)
```

**index.php**

Now read your excel file and extract the desired query part of the URL i.e text part of the URL after ?, like this:

(Replace `excel.xlsx` with your file name)

```
<?php

    // Include PHPExcel.php
    include 'PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

    $inputFileName = 'excel.xlsx';  // replace excel.xlsx with your file name

    //  Read your Excel workbook
    try {
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
    }

    //  Get worksheet dimension
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
    $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 

    // Loop through each row
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $highestRow; $i++){
        $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator($i)->current();

        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

        // Loop through each cell
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            $cell = $cell->getValue();

            // display only the query part of the URL
            echo parse_url($cell)['query'] . "<br />";
        }
    }

?>
```